Is the Dhamma for the discontented?
Is there a short discourse that says something like 'the dhama is not for the discontented, but for the content'. I am pretty certain there is. Can you post it?

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an08/an08.030.than.html


... desires, not for one with strong desires. (2) This Dhamma is for
one who is content, not for one who is discontent. (3) This Dhamma
is...

AN 8.30 Anuruddhamahāvitakkasutta
